Replacing Gurobi by a freeware solver when clustering the network job of the PyPSA-eur default configuration
PyPSA-eur runs well in the tutorial, but I have an error in the clustering network job of the default PyPSA-eur configuration because Gurobi is not installed.
I checked in the documentation that it can be replaced by HIGHS and did that in the config.yaml file:
solver:
name: highs
options: highs-default
It computes some results but it gave an error again in the clustering network job:
RuleException:
CalledProcessError in file D:\PyPSA\pypsa-eur\rules/build_electricity.smk, line 511:
Command 'C:/ProgramData/miniforge3/envs/pypsa-eur/python.exe "D:\PyPSA\pypsa-eur.snakemake\scripts\tmp9r91wvgi.cluster_network.py"' returned non-zero exit status 1.
What can I do to solve it?
